# How to "Command not supported" in keil uvision 5.30 for STM32F4

Tags: arm, stm32, keil, stm32f4discovery

I'm using STM board STM32F407VG with the ide KEIL MDK5.30. I have tried to flash the basic blinky example to the board. After building the code with 0 error and warning clicked on the download button to flash to the board. At that time an dialogue box popping out with a message "Command not supported". After that the process is failed with a message "Error: Flash Download failed  -  Target DLL has been cancelled".

ST-link is detected by the IDE (ST-LINK/V2-1).

What exactly need to be done here to solve this issue?

(In a different forum I found a fix like download the previous version MDK and copy the C:\Keil_v5\ARM\STLink\ST-LINKIII-KEIL_SWO.dll DLL file from the installation folder of previous version MDK to the corresponding folder of latest using MDK.

It will be helpful if anybody shares how to get the previous version MDK)

Comment: STM32F407VG is a chip you mean the related discovery board or some other board?

Comment: you can use opencd or you can use a serial solution and talk to the bootloader not limited to kiel's solution.

Comment: Have you added a target configuration in the flasher settings and did you reconfigure the program pins to some other function?

Comment: If the tool is corrupted for st-link then you will have to re-install the st-link manually. Configure the path again in Keil.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

Try this way.

1. Open Pack Installer program.
2. Find Packs.
3. Device Specific -> Keil::STM324xx_DFP.
4. Remove the latest version.
5. Install previous version (like 2.12.0(2018-02-22) version).